# How can I use a for-loop to examine a two-dimensional array from a two-dimensional array?

Tags: python

What I want is to repeat the 10x10 array by 3x3 array. For example, an array of 3x3 contains nine values of indexes [0][0:3], [1][0:3], [2][0:3], and I want to find the max value of these nine values and apply them to a new array. I will add a picture and what I tried.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI8IC.png)

[1[image: ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/22AUB.png]

```
array_33 = []
new_list = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        array_33.append([i:i+3])
max_value = max(map(max, array_33)    # to find a max_vlaue in 3x3 array
new_list.append(max_value)
```

One row succeeded in finding a value up to index [0:3], but the next row failed to find a way to get a value up to [0:3]. The value [8:10] is not divided by 3, so the value is added to the new array as it is. Then I want to do a repetitive task of finding a value of [0:3] from lines 4 to 6. I dont know how can i do this

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please can you try to clarify your question a bit by specifying exactly what output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 2D slicing from `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[(i+1)%10 for i in range(10)]]*10)
print(a)

sz = 3
b = [[np.max(a[i:i+3, j:j+3])
      for j in range(0,a.shape[1],sz)]
      for i in range(0,a.shape[0],sz)]
print(b)
```

generally, `a[row1:row2, col1:col2]` will give you the submatrix in those indexes (not including the last index)